# Android Studio taking too much CPU processing and Ram

Tags: android, android-studio

Hi there Android developers,i have a **core i5 HP Probook**,attach below is the screenshot of the task manager when i just started my android studio,are these normal figures,it sometimes shoot out of the CPU processing as well,should i change my machine or there are any optimization tools available..

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Looks fine to me. It's not your computer's fault, IDEs are just getting heavier.

Comment: The Android Studio its getting heavier because it have a lot of new features running behind, so it is not an issue on your pc. You have to deal with this, or enhance your development pc to get better performance.

Answer (score 0):

this is kind of "normal" on Android Studio i think, i heard some of friends of mine complained about that

Answer (score 0):

Absolute normal behaviour, especially on a mobile i5, I have an 3570k@4.2ghz and the whole system freezes when building. I solved that by right-clicking the taskmanager > gotodetails > find the process with the higher usage > set affinity > unselect one or more core

Your can also go on AS > File > Power Saver Mode, witch I belive would require you to run code analysis manually